# EAV Select query from spreaded value tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-attribute-value

I have the following SQL Server database structure I have to use to query data. The model could be wrong; I appreciate arguments if that's the case so I can ask for changes. If not, I need a query to get tabbed data in the format I will detail below.

The structure goes like this:

`CLIENTS`:

```
ClientID    ClientName
-----------------------
1           James
2           Leonard
3           Montgomery
```

`ATTRIBUTES`:

```
AttributeID     AttributeName
-----------------------------
1               Rank
2               Date
3               Salary
4               FileRecordsAmount
```

`ATTRIBUTES_STRING`:

```
ClientID    AttributeID     AttributeStringValue
1           1               Captain
2           1               Chief Surgeon
3           1               Chief Engineer
```

`ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC`:

```
ClientID    AttributeID     AttributeNumericValue
1           4               187
2           4               2
3           4               10
```

The result I need would be the following:

```
RESULTS:
----------------------------------------------------------
ClientID    ClientName  Rank            FileRecordsAmount
1           James       Captain         187
2           Leonard     Chief Surgeon   2
3           Montgomery  Chief Engineer  10
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: The challenging issue here (for me) is that the attributes are dynamic... I have 5 tables of attributes (ATTRIBUTES_STRING, ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC, ATTRIBUTES_DATE, ATTRIBUTES_BIT, ATTRIBUTES_INT) and the user should be able to set up it's own attributes.

Comment: well; so far I'm managing that from code; I run several selects and checking for existence on the ATTRIBUTES_XXX tables (I got 5 of them; string, date, bit, double and integer's attributes tables). I'd like to use a "cleaner" solution with a direct query...

Comment: [Read this true story about how EAV tables sank a whole company](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) and then following the advice given: ***RUN LIKE HELL!*** - EAV are the devil - either re-architect, or leave that job .....

Comment: thank you for the article marc, it's very interesting; however this case is not that difficult (1 table with 240 fields? omg!); the whole layout has 40 tables, the "eav" only "affects" 1 table. Well, that aside, what would you recommend for dynamic attributes? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need an SQL join. It will look something like this:

```
select 
    CLIENTS.ClientID, 
    CLIENTS.ClientName, 
    ATTRIBUTES_STRING1.AttributeStringValue as Rank, 
    ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC2.AttributeNumericValue as FileRecordsAmount
from 
    CLIENTS,
    ATTRIBUTES ATTRIBUTES1,
    ATTRIBUTES ATTRIBUTES2,
    ATTRIBUTES_STRING ATTRIBUTES_STRING1,
    ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC2
where CLIENTS.ClientID = ATTRIBUTES_STRING1.ClientID
and CLIENTS.ClientID = ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC2.ClientID
and ATTRIBUTES_STRING1.AttributeID = ATTRIBUTES1.AttributeID
and ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC2.AttributeID = ATTRIBUTES2.AttributeID
and ATTRIBUTES1.AttributeName = 'Rank'
and ATTRIBUTES2.AttributeName = 'FileRecordsAmount'
;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62d33/2) for reference. This is my first EAV schema so I wouldn't put too much trust in it :)

**Edit:** Schema provided below for reference:

```
create table CLIENTS (
    ClientID integer primary key,
    ClientName varchar(50) not null
);

insert into CLIENTS values (1,'James');
insert into CLIENTS values (2,'Leonard');
insert into CLIENTS values (3,'Montgomery');

create table ATTRIBUTES (
    AttributeID integer primary key,
    AttributeName varchar(50) not null
);

create index ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IDX on ATTRIBUTES (AttributeName);

insert into ATTRIBUTES values (1,'Rank');
insert into ATTRIBUTES values (2,'Date');
insert into ATTRIBUTES values (3,'Salary');
insert into ATTRIBUTES values (4,'FileRecordsAmount');

create table ATTRIBUTES_STRING (
    ClientID integer,
    AttributeID integer not null,
    AttributeStringValue varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (ClientID, AttributeID)
);

insert into ATTRIBUTES_STRING values (1,1,'Captain');
insert into ATTRIBUTES_STRING values (2,1,'Chief Surgeon');
insert into ATTRIBUTES_STRING values (3,1,'Chief Engineer');

create table ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC (
    ClientID integer,
    AttributeID integer not null,
    AttributeNumericValue numeric(10, 5) not null,
    primary key (ClientID, AttributeID)
);
insert into ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC values (1,4,187);
insert into ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC values (2,4,2);
insert into ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC values (3,4,10);
```

**Edit:** Modified the select to make it easier to extend with extra attributes

Comment: Thank you very much, dwurf! I've tried fiddle, since I've read an answer somewhere referring to it, but I couldn't get anything except for the error "'CONCAT_WS' is not a recognized built-in function name...". The solution you provide works, but maybe it was because I didn't clarify enough (I will edit my question), the attributes table is dynamic. I mean, in the example I put only 2 attribute's tables of the five I have. Notice I've configured 4 attributes but I only use 2 of them for this case.

Comment: For each additional attribute you want in your result set you have to add an alias to `ATTRIBUTES` (eg `ATTRIBUTES3`), another reference to your `ATTRIBUTES_<TYPE>` tables (eg `ATTRIBUTES_STRING_2`), a join between `CLIENT` and your `ATTRIBUTES_<TYPE>` table on `ClientID`, a join between `ATTRIBUTES_<TYPE>` and your `ATTRIBUTES` alias on `AttributeID`, and a condition on the `AttributeName` (eg `AttributeName = 'Salary'`). This sounds complex but if you follow the pattern I've established in the `select` statement you'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Ah, I understand your question a little better now - thanks for the clarification. You have two options: either build a query like the one I've provided in your client-side code, or build a query like the one I've provided using T-SQL. Either way you need to scan the `ATTRIBUTES` table then build the query based on the available attributes. If you can store the type associated with each attribute you can join to the correct `ATTRIBUTES_<TYPE>` table as I've done, otherwise you could just join to *all* types for each attribute (slower and more verbose, but it will work).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, again. The tip you're giving to me, to join the correct ATTRIBUTE_TYPE, would be something to do within my code to dinamically build the "correct" sql sentence?

Comment: If possible, store a type in the `ATTRIBUTES` table. This would require your users to specify a type when they create the attribute.

Comment: There is a type, but since I'd like to solve if from sql, and sql doesn't supprot (does not?) case/switch, and I was looking for an alternative solution which does not involve coding, I've omitted it.

Comment: You could join to all of your different type tables, or join `WHERE (ATTRIBUTES1.AttributeType = 'String' and ATTRIBUTES1.AttributeId = ATTRIBUTES_STRING_1.AttributeID) or (ATTRIBUTES1.AttributeType = 'Numeric' and ATTRIBUTES1.AttributeId = ATTRIBUTES_NUMERIC_1.AttributeID) or ...`. At this point the SQL feels really ugly, I'm starting to see where all the hatred for EAV comes from! (I've never used it myself).