# How to query for all information of an entity within an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I've searched about this and tried to make it myself over the last few days but I just couldn't. The closest I've gotten within my search was this answer, also on Stack Overflow: [EAV Select query from spreaded value tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679399/eav-select-query-from-spreaded-value-tables)

So here I am, turning myself to the Internet!

So, I have a database which makes use of the EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) model. But here's the catch: the actual entities aren't directly connected to the other EAV tables. Let me be more specific; say that there is a Person and a Site tables, and that they only have their primary keys: `person_id` and `site_id`, respectively.

Because the attributes (called "properties" on my schema) of those entities (i.e. the Person and the Site) must be dynamic, they must all be stored outside their respective tables, i.e. the EAV tables. The following is the EAV part of the database schema (I'm not sure if it's completely correct, so please let me know if you have any suggestion). --  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN3dy.png

The EAV part of the schema basically has the following tables:

- `property`
- `property_value_varchar`
- `property_value_text`
- `property_value_number`
- `property_value_boolean`
- `property_value_datetime`
- `entity_tables`

Ok, so, since the Entities aren't "directly connected" to the EAV part, I'm using the `entity_tables` table just as a reference to the actual tables, so, with the example above, the `entity_tables` table should look something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
|entity_table_id | entity_table_name  |
|      1         |       person       |
|      2         |       site         |
|      .         |        .           |
|      .         |        .           |
---------------------------------------
```

The `property` table is the one that actually holds the different properties that any entity can hold, say "PERSON_FIRST_NAME" or "LOCATION_NAME", or anything else.

The `property_value_*` tables are all exactly the same except on the datatype of the `property_value`. These are the ones that hold the actual value of each Entity's object's property, which get mapped by the `entity_table_id` and `entity_object_id`.

Let me give you a possible instance of the database, for clarity:

```
Person table
-------------
| person_id |
|     1     |
|     2     |
-------------

Site table
-----------
| site_id |
|    1    |
|    2    |
-----------

entity_tables table
---------------------------------------
|entity_table_id | entity_table_name  |
|      1         |       person       |
|      2         |       site         |
---------------------------------------

property table
-------------------------------------
| property_id |    property_code    |
|      1      |   PERSON_FIRST_NAME |
|      2      |   PERSON_LAST_NAME  |
|      3      |   PERSON_BIRTH_DATE |
|      4      |   SITE_NAME         |
|      5      |   SITE_PHONE_NR_1   |
|      6      |   SITE_PHONE_NR_2   |
|      7      |   SITE_LATITUDE     |
|      8      |   SITE_LONGITUDE    |
|      9      |   SITE_CITY         |
|     10      |   SITE_COUNTRY      |
|     11      |   SITE_ZIP_CODE     |
-------------------------------------

property_value_varchar table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property_value_id | property_id | entity_table_id | entity_object_id | property_value |
|         1         |      1      |        1        |         1        |     Richard    |
|         2         |      2      |        1        |         1        |     Hammer     |
|         3         |      1      |        1        |         2        |     Bruce      |
|         4         |      2      |        1        |         2        |     Heaton     |
|         5         |      4      |        2        |         1        |     BatCave    |
|         6         |      5      |        2        |         1        |  +49123456789  |
|         7         |      4      |        2        |         2        |   BigCompany   |
|         8         |      5      |        2        |         2        |    987654321   |
|         9         |      6      |        2        |         2        |    147852369   |
|        10         |      9      |        2        |         2        |      Berlin    |
|        11         |     10      |        2        |         2        |     Germany    |
|        12         |     11      |        2        |         2        |      14167     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

property_value_datetime table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property_value_id | property_id | entity_table_id | entity_object_id | property_value |
|         1         |      3      |        1        |         1        |   1985-05-31   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

property_value_number table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property_value_id | property_id | entity_table_id | entity_object_id | property_value |
|         1         |      7      |        2        |         1        |    1.402636    |
|         2         |      8      |        2        |         1        |    7.273922    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

(property_value_text and property_value_boolean tables are empty)
```

---

As you could see, not all objects of each entity have necessarily the same properties (attributes). The domain is really loose like that.

So, now like so many people before me, I'm not sure how to retrieve all of this information in a readable way, namely how can I get all of the information concerning the records of the Person table or of the Site table?

Namely, how can I get something like this:

```
 Person table view
----------------------------------------------------
| Person ID |     Property code   | Property value |
|     1     |   PERSON_FIRST_NAME |    Richard     |
|     1     |   PERSON_LAST_NAME  |    Hammer      |
|     1     |   PERSON_BIRTH_DATE |   1985-05-31   |
|     2     |   PERSON_FIRST_NAME |    Bruce       |
|     2     |   PERSON_LAST_NAME  |    Heaton      |
----------------------------------------------------

 Site table view
------------------------------------------------
| Site ID | Property code    |  Property value |
|    1    |  SITE_NAME       |  Batcave        |
|    1    |  SITE_PHONE_NR_1 |  +49123456789   |
|    1    |  SITE_LATITUDE   |  1.402636       |
|    1    |  SITE_LONGITUDE  |  7.273922       |
|    2    |  SITE_NAME       |  BigCompany     |
|    2    |  SITE_PHONE_NR_1 |  987654321      |
|    2    |  SITE_PHONE_NR_2 |  147852369      |
|    2    |  SITE_CITY       |  Berlin         |
|    2    |  SITE_COUNTRY    |  Germany        |
|    2    |  SITE_ZIP_CODE   |  14167          |
------------------------------------------------
```

Or even like this, if it is easier:

```
Person table view
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Person ID | PERSON_FIRST_NAME | PERSON_LAST_NAME | PERSON_BIRTH_DATE |
|     1     |      Richard      |       Hammer     |     1985-05-31    |
|     2     |       Bruce       |       Heaton     |                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Site table view
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Site ID | SITE_NAME  | SITE_PHONE_NR_1 | SITE_PHONE_NR_2 | SITE_LATITUDE | SITE_LONGITUDE | SITE_CITY | SITE_COUNTRY | SITE_ZIP_CODE |
|    1    | Batcave    |   +49123456789  |                 |   1.402636    |    7.273922    |           |              |               |
|    2    | BigCompany |    987654321    |   147852369     |               |                |  Berlin   |   Germany    |     14167     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I realize this can be quite confusing. Please let me know how else I can help you help me, like more information or better explaining of some part.

I also don't expect 1 SQL query (per entity) to do the trick. I realize that more than 1 query is likely and that it/they would very likely need to be "assembled" by PHP (for instance), in order to really make it dynamic. So even if someone could even just explain me how I could get all of this info just for the hypothetical properties (attribute) that I have above, I would already be immensely grateful!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Unfortunately, EAV is generally an antipattern.  It makes the kinds of queries you want very cumbersome to write -- you wind up having to "hard-code" a lot of the stuff that you have carefully avoided "hard-coding" into a schema, losing any benefit.  In particular, the *type* of a `SELECT` query column cannot depend on the *contents* of a table -- it must be known at query time, or discoverable from the *type* of a table column or expression, so the only way to write a query that would produce output like your first example would be to join on *every* `result_value_...` table and merge...

Comment: ... the results into a single field with `COALESCE()` or similar.  But then the type of the column will necessarily become some lowest-common-denominator type (probably unbounded `VARCHAR`), so you can't perform most sensible operations on them (e.g. you could not add 5 to each value, even if you knew they were originally numeric, without first explicitly converting to a numeric type).  Some RDBMSs (perhaps MySQL, I dunno) have "pivoting" extensions that might allow rows to be converted into columns as per your later snippets, but this is TTBOMK not standard SQL.

Comment: If you went with EAV in the first place to allow users to write highly customisable queries, my suggestion would be to redesign your DB schema in the usual way (i.e. with a fixed set of hardcoded columns), and offer the user query flexibility by allowing them to choose fields, tables etc. from lists that you extract from the DB via its special metadata system tables (all DBs offer this, e.g. via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`) and then build a customised `SELECT` command from that.

Comment: OTOH if you went with EAV to allow users the ultimate flexibility in adding columns to a table, you'll have to accept that this flexibility means that the DB "knows very little" about that data, so it won't be possible to do much more with it than treat it as blobs of arbitrary text or binary data.  (E.g. as you'll find, trying to allow such "columns" to several different types is a nightmare, and forget trying to index by such a column.)  Finally, EAV is essentially this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Comment: @j_random_hacker Indeed, the idea of using EAV came from the necessity of allowing the (right) users to define (frontend-wise) which attributes a certain object has. Sure, it is trivial for people and locations, but there are other entities within the database which are not so obvious when it comes to defining what "is" (or "what makes") it. Say, an "Organization". What is it? Is it a company, an organized group of people, or something else? Does it have a name? Maybe a certain internal or external ID code? Dynamic, ...

Comment: ... Dynamic, undefined stuff like that, so the columns can't really be hardcoded like that (can they?)

A discussed alternative for this was to use a different kind of database, like MongoDB or Neo4j, but the thought was scratched due to lack of (did I say 'lack'? I meant 'no') experience with any of those. The experience is mainly with MySQL, like so many other developers out there. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to allow these users *total* flexibility, then you're essentially writing a generic front-end to a RDBMS -- and I'm sure that such things exist already.  But I think you probably want to only offer them *some* flexibility.  In that case I'd suggest setting up fixed tables (and indices, etc.) in your DB schema for the main business entities that won't change.  If you want to offer the user the ability to add extra properties to the rows of these tables, you could create `ALTER TABLE` commands from their input, but I think a better (safer) solution would be to...

Comment: ... allow them only to create or delete entirely new DB tables in the schema that have as (part or all of) their PK an FK to of one of your "standard" tables.  (You can effectively "add columns" to an existing table by creating another table with the same PK.)  I prefer this to `ALTER TABL` since it seems less likely that some important standard column could be accidentally broken this way.  Either way, in contrast to your EAV solution, the DB "knows about" the real structure of the data, so it can index on it, evaluate expressions on it in `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This was a fun question! This can be handled with dynamic sql. In the code below, the schema has been recreated with temp tables. The code could be turned into a stored procedure that takes an entity_table_id as a parameter and then selects the entity_object_id as entity_table_name + 'id' followed by every property_value as columns with the corresponding property_code as the headings.

```
-- load EAV tables
if object_id('tempdb..#entity_tables') is not null
    drop table #entity_tables
create table #entity_tables(entity_table_id int,entity_table_name varchar(255))
insert into #entity_tables values
    (1,'person'),
    (2,'site')
if object_id('tempdb..#property') is not null
    drop table #property
create table #property(property_id int,property_code varchar(255))
insert into #property values
    (1,'PERSON_FIRST_NAME'),
    (2,'PERSON_LAST_NAME'),
    (3,'PERSON_BIRTH_DATE'),
    (4,'SITE_NAME'),
    (5,'SITE_PHONE_NR_1'),
    (6,'SITE_PHONE_NR_2'),
    (7,'SITE_LATITUDE'),
    (8,'SITE_LONGITUDE'),
    (9,'SITE_CITY'),
    (10,'SITE_COUNTRY'),
    (11,'SITE_ZIP_CODE')
if object_id('tempdb..#property_value_varchar') is not null
    drop table #property_value_varchar
create table #property_value_varchar(property_value_id int,property_id int,entity_table_id int,entity_object_id int,property_value varchar(255))
insert into #property_value_varchar values
    (1,1,1,1,'Richard'),
    (2,2,1,1,'Hammer'),
    (3,1,1,2,'Bruce'),
    (4,2,1,2,'Heaton'),
    (5,4,2,1,'BatCave'),
    (6,5,2,1,'+49123456789'),
    (7,4,2,2,'BigCompany'),
    (8,5,2,2,'987654321'),
    (9,6,2,2,'147852369'),
    (10,9,2,2,'Berlin'),
    (11,10,2,2,'Germany'),
    (12,11,2,2,'14167')
if object_id('tempdb..#property_value_datetime') is not null
    drop table #property_value_datetime
create table #property_value_datetime(property_value_id int,property_id int,entity_table_id int,entity_object_id int,property_value datetime)
insert into #property_value_datetime values
(1,3,1,1,'1985-05-31')
if object_id('tempdb..#property_value_number') is not null
    drop table #property_value_number
create table #property_value_number(property_value_id int,property_id int,entity_table_id int,entity_object_id int,property_value float)
insert into #property_value_number values
(1,7,2,1,1.402636),
(2,8,2,1,7.273922)

-- create dynamic sql to get all data conditioned on #entity_tables.table_id value
declare @tableid int,@sql varchar(max)
set @tableid = 1 -- this could be passed as a parameter

-- get pivot code with #ColumnList# placeholders to be added below
select @sql = 'select entity_object_id ' + entity_table_name + 'id,
    #ColumnListCast#
from    (
        select
            e.entity_table_name,
            pv.entity_object_id,
            pv.property_value,
            p.property_code
        from #entity_tables e
            inner join  (
                        select entity_table_id,entity_object_id,property_id,property_value from #property_value_varchar union all
                        select entity_table_id,entity_object_id,property_id,cast(property_value as varchar(255)) from #property_value_datetime union all
                        select entity_table_id,entity_object_id,property_id,cast(property_value as varchar(255)) from #property_value_number
                        ) pv
                on pv.entity_table_id = e.entity_table_id
            inner join #property p
                on p.property_id = pv.property_id
        where e.entity_table_id = ' + cast(@tableid as varchar(5)) + '
        ) p
    pivot   (
            max(property_value)
            for property_code in    (
                                    #ColumnList#
                                    )
            ) piv' from #entity_tables where entity_table_id = @tableid

-- get column list with cast version for diffferent data types
declare @ColumnList varchar(max),
        @ColumnListCast nvarchar(max)
set @ColumnList = ''
set @ColumnListCast = ''
select  @ColumnList = @ColumnList + '[' + p.property_code + ']' + case row_number() over(order by p.property_id desc) when 1 then '' else ',' end,
        @ColumnListCast = @ColumnListCast + 'cast([' + p.property_code + '] as ' + t.CastValue + ') [' + p.property_code + ']' + case row_number() over(order by p.property_id desc) when 1 then '' else ',' end
from #property p
    inner join  (
                select property_id,'varchar(255)' CastValue from #property_value_varchar where entity_table_id = @tableid union
                select property_id,'datetime' CastValue from #property_value_datetime where entity_table_id = @tableid union
                select property_id,'float' CastValue from #property_value_number where entity_table_id = @tableid
                ) t
        on t.property_id = p.property_id
order by p.property_id

set @sql = replace(replace(@sql,'#ColumnList#',@ColumnList),'#ColumnListCast#',@ColumnListCast)

exec(@sql)
```